# how to set windows 7 resolution to 16:9 in virtualbox running in ubuntu 12.04 as a host?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox, resolution

I have installed Virtualbox in Ubuntu 12.04, and I created a virtual guest with Windows 7 64bit. Guest additions were also installed. It works fine, but I can't set the resolution to anything higher than 1600 x 1200, whereas my screen is 1920x1080.

Here's my system specifications: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3632QM CPU @ 2.20GHz AMD Radeon 7650 VGA 8 Gb RAM DDR3

Moreover, if I try to enhable 3D acceleration in the settings of my guest, when I expand to full screen it aborts...

Thanks in advance

Gabriele

Comment: Have you installed the guest additions yet.

Comment: yep... I did, since the beginning. To no avail actually

Answer (score 0):

My guess is VirtualBox is not allocating sufficient video memory to the guest OS? If you go to Settings -> Display -> Video memory, how much is allocated?  Perhaps give it a boost.  Windows will always disable the option for any resolutions that the 'hardware' can't support.

This should probably be a comment, but i'm too reputation-poor to do so :)